# is it safe to add a value to a std::deque iterator

Tags: c++, deque

std::deque unlike std::vector is not always contiguous in memory.

is it safe, for example to do this :

```
std::size_t pos;
//... compute pos ...
mydeque.erase(mydeque.begin(), mydeque.begin() + pos);
```

knowing that "mydeque.begin() + pos", is in the deque range ?

I read that the iterator is "RandomAccessIterator" so normally it's safe, am I right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is safe, as long as you are in the range (up to the `end()`). This is basically the operation `std::advance` does for random access iterators.

Answer (score 1):

When you're adding a value *N* to an iterator you're simply advancing the iterator by *N* steps. It has nothing to do with how the data is stored in the collection being iterated over.